# enable ajax add to cart buttons on single pages on woocommerce shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add ajax functionality to add to cart button on single product pages on woocommerce shop, on archive pages it does ajax, but on single product pages it doesnt, I believe this is the default behavior but is there a way to achieve my goal? been binging and googling with no luck.

Comment: Yes. There is no option for it to it with woocommerce admin. We can do it by calling jQuery function of AJAX addtocart button in our own plugin or theme.

Answer (score 3):

For the time being this isn't possible specially for variable or non simple products

References:

```
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2353
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/5039
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/Roadmap
```

Comment: Update: This is possible for simple products only on product archive page. See gist https://gist.github.com/Jplus2/0c44d052e5889bce2ab9

Comment: add-to-cart.php goes to woocommerce template override folder -> loop -> add-to-cart.php. Just override the contents.